# R: How do I write more than 2 decimal places to a SPSS file (.sav)?

Tags: r, decimal, spss

I want to write a correlation matrix to an SPSS file.  The file format is .sav and the format of the required correaltion matrix is a mixture of character string columns and numeric columns (mostly numeric).  SPSS automatically recognises strings as nominal data and numbers as scale data.  If SPSS does not recognise the columns as nominal or scale then I cannot load the SPSS file directly into AMOS for some modelling.  When I write a dataframe as a .sav file using the write.sav (df, "filename", digits = x) function from the misty package, SPSS will recognise the numbers as scale data but limits the decimal places to 2 and in the case of 0.999 SPSS rounds the value up to 1.00.  I need SPSS to recognise my dataframe numbers to 5 or 8 decimal places.  If anyone can help me solve this - I would be very grateful!

I´ve ensured that the dataframe column types are correct before writing the .sav file and I have tried converting the dataframe to a tibble and ensuring the columns are the correct class before writing the .sav file.  In both cases, SPSS only loads the .sav files with two decimal points.  I have checked the settings in SPSS and of course SPSS will display .sav files generated by itself to any number of deicmal points and .csv files.  Writing a .csv file from R and then importing to SPSS is a work-around but sub-optimal as I need to write a workable file direct to the .sav format that SPSS and AMOS will read correctly to many deicmal points.  Note that SPSS will display more deicmal places if the numeric values are written to the .sav file as strings, however, the .sav file will not then load into AMOS because the columns are recognised by SPSS as nominal data (strings) and not scale data (numbers).  Ultimately, I need a .sav file that causes SPSS to recognise numeric data as scale data with more than 2 decimal places.  AMOS just follows whatever SPSS does.

Some test code could be:

```
install.packages("misty")

library(misty)

col1 = c(0.111,0.222,0.333)

col2 = c(0.444,0.555,0.666)

col3 = c(0.777,0.888,0.999)

df = data.frame(col1, col2, col3)

df

str(df)

write.sav(df,"test.sav", digits = 5)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have the same issue with `haven::write_sav()`?

Comment: Also, you’re certain the actual values have been rounded, rather than just being rounded in the data viewer? eg, if you manually increase the decimal places in the variables tab after opening in SPSS, does the data viewer then show `0.999` or `1.000`?

Comment: Hi zephryl.  Thanks for looking at this.  Q2:  Yes same problem with haven::write_sav().  I think write.sav uses haven::write_sav() as a call.  I elected to go for write.sav because it has a digits option that control the number of digits written the .sav file.

Comment: Q1:  You are correct.  The values are being rounded in the data viewer (and not the written file) when SPSS reads the written values as numeric, however, this does not happen if the .sav file is written by SPSS itself.  So I´m guessing there is some kind of file header information that the SPSS written file includes and maybe 2 decimal places is an SPSS default?  I´ve tried changing this default in SPSS options but to no avail.  Write.Sav indicates that it can include header information but not for measurement type or decimal places (if such things exist in a .sav file?).

Comment: It is not in scope to go through every .sav file written from R and change the decimal places for every variable - it´s just too much manual work for the number of variables and files.

Comment: as long as the underlying values are correct, it doesn't matter what the display length in SPSS is. eg, AMOS will still import and use the value `0.999` in models even if it displays as `1.00` in the data viewer. So there's no need to change the display length if that's your goal. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Zephryl, Sadly, AMOS does not read all the decimal points. It treats the file like SPSS and only loads 2 decimal points. I can see this when I view the file from AMOS and also when I run the SEM. I have to work with correlated z-scores and only having 2 decimal places is not accurate enough and producing Heywood cases. If you can find a work around I would be most grateful. Thank you.